# Erro ao acessar dados no Mysql com EF6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

Quando tento acessar os dados no MySQL via `lambda`(`EF`), o Visual Studio retorna o seguinte erro:

> Falha no método >'MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.set_DbConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)' ao tentar acessar o método 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Settings()'.

Tentei procurar na internet mas não achei algo que pudesse me ajudar com esse erro. Segue o Código da Main Controller

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;
using MySql.Data.Entity;
using System.Media;
using View.Model;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace View
{
public class MainController
{
    remoteEntities remote = new remoteEntities();

    public bool validaLogin(string usuario, string senha)
    {
        string novaSenha = getMD5Hash(senha);
        var resultado = remote.Motorista.Select(x => new { x.ID, x.Login, x.Senha, x.Nome }).Where(u => u.Login == usuario && u.Senha == novaSenha).ToList();
        if (resultado.Count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static string getMD5Hash(string input)
    {
        var md5Hash = MD5.Create();
        // Converter a String para array de bytes, que é como a biblioteca trabalha.
        var data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        // Cria-se um StringBuilder para recompôr a string.
        var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop para formatar cada byte como uma String em hexadecimal
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }

    #region Testa Conexão

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private static extern bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

    public static bool checkConnection()
    {
        int desc;
        bool hasConnection = InternetGetConnectedState(out desc, 0);
        if (hasConnection)
            hasConnection = webClient("http://zerohoravirtual.com/");

        return hasConnection;
    }

    private static bool webClient(string _url)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest webReq;
        System.Net.WebResponse resp;
        webReq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_url);

        try
        {
            resp = webReq.GetResponse();
            resp.Close();
            webReq = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            webReq = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

**Update 1**

Conexão criada com o ADO.Net, versão do conector .net 8.0.10-rc e versão do plugin do visual studio 2.0.5 m4

Comment: como você configurou a conexão?

Comment: Configurei direitamente pelo ado.net

Comment: Então mostre toda a sequencia, o problema me parece ser nesse ponto ... só o erro em si não tem como ter certeza de nada!

Comment: Pronto amigo, postei a classe inteira.

Comment: essa -> remoteEntities

Comment: Minha entidade, ta errada?

Comment: pode ser tanta coisa, talvez o driver, talvez a conexão sei lá ... talvez ... é dificil reproduzir seu erro.

Comment: O que é estranho é que eu removo o conector, o plugin, a conexão com o banco, removo tudo e ainda assim quando adiciono novamente ele da erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, seguindo os passos de uma outra pergunta que havia postado aqui no SOpt. 
Link: [Problema com Mysql net connector e Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274493/problema-com-mysql-net-connector-e-entity-framework)

Ao criar o modelo de entidade, no App.config é criado a seguinte dependência:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.10.0" newVersion="8.0.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Altere a dependência para:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.11.0" newVersion="6.9.11.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Pois quando instalado o Mysql para Visual Studio na versão 2.0.5 m4, ele cria a dependência com a versão RC do Mysql Connector/Net e como não está realmente instalada a versão RC é retornado esse erro. Alterando a dependência o erro desaparece.