# Problema com Mysql net connector e Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, wpf, entity-framework-6

Quando instalo o conector do mysql na versão 6.9.11, consigo ver o driver para o ADO.Net, até ai tudo bem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando tento criar o modelo recebo o seguinte erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando instalo a versão do conector 6.10.6, não consigo ver o driver para o ADO.Net e também não consigo fazer a conexão.

Dados para ajuda:

Mysql for Visual Studio => 2.0.5 m4

Mysql Connector/Net => 6.9.11

Visual Studio 2017 => 15.5.4

Obs. Já tentei usar o Mysql for Visual Studio 1.2.7 e também não obtenho resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver seguindo as etapas da resposta de uma pergunta do SOen.
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748396/mysql-is-not-appearing-in-choose-data-source-for-visual-studio-2017

Etapas com algumas alterações nos links, seguindo o original.

Nota: siga as etapas na mesma ordem.

Desinstale / remova "Conector/NET" e "MySQL para Visual Studio", se instalado.

Instale o "MySQL para Visual Studio" v2.0.5 m4 ([MySQL para Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/)). Nota: Instale o MySQL para o Visual Studio antes do Connector/NET.

Instale "Connector/NET" v6.9.11 ([Conector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)).

Nota: tentei usar Connector/NET v6.8, v6.10 e v8 primeiro, mas nenhum deles trabalhou com Visual Studio 2017 e ADO.Net. [Aqui você pode encontrar todas as Versões e Compatibilidades do Conector com IDE do Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html) , mas até agora esta lista é imprecisa. (Verídico)

Nota: até esta etapa, você deve ser coberto, mas você encontrará os problemas do Entity Framework, siga as próximas etapas para configurar completamente o seu ambiente e você deve estar pronto para ir.

Baixe e instale "EntityFramework" v6.2.0 através do NuGet, indo para a Aba do Projeto / Gerencie o NuGet Packages / Browse -> Entity Framework.

Adicionar referências a C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9.11\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll e  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector.NET 6.9.11\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll; pelo direito clicando em Referências dentro do Solution Explorer e selecionando Add Reference / Browse -> Browse button.

Adicione informações do provedor do MySQL EF6 dentro do App.config sob fornecedores de estrutura de entidade, conforme segue:

```
<entityFramework>
       <providers>
         <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
              type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
       </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Reconstrua o projeto indo para Build tab / Rebuild ProjectName.
E é isso. VS2017 está pronto para ir. Espero que isso funcione para todos, como aconteceu comigo hoje.